# Динамическая загрузка dll библиотек C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, dll

У меня есть следующий код для загрузки dll из папки:

```
private List<IBookFormatPlugin> LoadPlugins(string pluginsDirectory)
{
List<IBookFormatPlugin> plugins = new List<IBookFormatPlugin>();

// Получение всех файлов .dll из папки pluginsDirectory
string[] dllFiles = Directory.GetFiles(pluginsDirectory, "*.dll");

foreach (string dllFile in dllFiles)
{
    try
    {
        // Загрузка сборки
        Assembly pluginAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllFile);
        string pluginName = pluginAssembly.GetName().Name;
        Console.WriteLine($"Имя сборки DLL: {pluginName}");

        // Получение версии сборки
        Version version = pluginAssembly.GetName().Version;
        Console.WriteLine($"Версия: {version}");
        object[] titleAttributes = pluginAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyTitleAttribute), false);
        if (titleAttributes.Length > 0)
        {
            AssemblyTitleAttribute titleAttribute = (AssemblyTitleAttribute)titleAttributes[0];
            Console.WriteLine($"Название: {titleAttribute.Title}");
        }

        object[] descriptionAttributes = pluginAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyDescriptionAttribute), false);
        if (descriptionAttributes.Length > 0)
        {
            AssemblyDescriptionAttribute descriptionAttribute = (AssemblyDescriptionAttribute)descriptionAttributes[0];
            Console.WriteLine($"Описание: {descriptionAttribute.Description}");
        }
        // Получение всех типов, реализующих интерфейс IBookFormatPlugin
        Type[] pluginTypes = pluginAssembly.GetTypes().Where(t => typeof(IBookFormatPlugin).IsAssignableFrom(t) && !t.IsInterface).ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine(pluginTypes.Length);
        // Создание экземпляров плагинов и добавление их в список
        foreach (Type pluginType in pluginTypes)
        {
            IBookFormatPlugin plugin = (IBookFormatPlugin)Activator.CreateInstance(pluginType);
            plugins.Add(plugin);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Обработка ошибок загрузки плагина
        Console.WriteLine($"Ошибка загрузки плагина из файла {dllFile}: {ex.Message}");
    }
}

return plugins;
}
```

А также несколько библиотек `dll` образованных от интерфейса `IBookFormatPlugin`

Пример одной из них:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using VersOne.Epub;

namespace epubPlugin
{
    public class epubReader : IBookFormatPlugin
    {
        bool IBookFormatPlugin.CanReadFormat(string filePath)
        {
            ...
        }

        string IBookFormatPlugin.FilterFormat()
        {
            ...
        }

        Book IBookFormatPlugin.InfoBook(string filePath)
        {
            ...
        }

        string IBookFormatPlugin.ReadBook(string filePath)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Вот также сам интерфейс:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace epubPlugin
{
    public interface IBookFormatPlugin
    {
        bool CanReadFormat(string filePath);
        Book InfoBook(string filePath);
        string ReadBook(string filePath);
        string FilterFormat();
    }
}
```

Проблема в том что `LoadPlugins` возвращает пустой список.

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка была в том что я не учитывал пространство имен для интерфейса

```
object[] descriptionAttributes = pluginAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyDescriptionAttribute), false);
if (descriptionAttributes.Length > 0)
{
    AssemblyDescriptionAttribute descriptionAttribute = (AssemblyDescriptionAttribute)descriptionAttributes[0];
    Console.WriteLine($"Описание: {descriptionAttribute.Description}");
}
string iMyInterfaceName = "." + typeof(IBookFormatPlugin).ToString();
Type[] defaultConstructorParametersTypes = new Type[0];
object[] defaultConstructorParameters = new object[0];

foreach (Type type in pluginAssembly.GetTypes())
{
    string ns = type.Namespace;
    if (type.GetInterface(ns + iMyInterfaceName) != null)
    {
        ConstructorInfo defaultConstructor = type.GetConstructor(defaultConstructorParametersTypes);
        object instance = defaultConstructor.Invoke(defaultConstructorParameters);
        plugins.Add(instance as IBookFormatPlugin);
    }
}
```

Comment: Подсказка, вместо `new T[0]` пишите `Array.Empty<T>()`, или в .NET 8 можно писать просто `[]`.